# Cartoon Effect in android OpenCV(Need to Convert from gray to colour)

Tags: java, opencv, android

I am trying to create a cartoon or sketch effect through opencv in android,for that i am using the logic in explained in the [Website](http://www.askaswiss.com/2016/01/how-to-create-cartoon-effect-opencv-python.html)

From that I am trying to create in android .Here is my code

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        Imgproc.bilateralFilter(inputFrame.gray(),co,9, 9, 7);

        Imgproc.medianBlur(inputFrame.gray(),gray, 7);
        Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(gray,gray, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY,9,2);

        Core.bitwise_and(co,gray,mOutputFrame);//ADDS THE BOTH IMAGES 

    return mOutputFrame;
}
```

**This works but the output is in *GRAY*.
what to do for getting this in *COLOR*?**

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame.html) of the `CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame` the method `gray()` returns a gray image from the frame. So changing it to `rgba()` will return the RGB color image to be passed to the filters you are using.

Comment: if gray() replaced with rgba() makes the app crash

Comment: Because `Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold` works on a 1-channel image not a color image. You can process each channel independently then merge them together.

Comment: `Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrame.gray(),co,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            Imgproc.bilateralFilter(co,co,9, 9, 7);
            Imgproc.medianBlur(inputFrame.gray(),gray, 7);
            Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(gray,gray, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY,9,2);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(co,co,Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
            Core.bitwise_and(co,gray,mOutputFrame);`

Comment: i tried this,in this co is 3 channel and gray is 1 channel.But not working